# Is there a way to use custom Liquid filters when transforming JSON objects to JSON using Azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

Here's the link to a tutorial I was reading over:
[Transform JSON and XML using Liquid templates as maps in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#liquid-template-considerations). It doesn't really say anything about using filters that I could code even though
Microsoft uses the DotLiquid implementation of Liquid which allows the making of custom filters. I'm not sure how or where I would be able to input any custom-made filters in; has anyone tried anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

You use Liquid filters inside your JSON template that need to be transformated.
You can use any of these filters:

1. Size
2. Slice
3. Downcase
4. UrlEncode
5. UrlDecode
6. Capitalize
7. Escape
8. Truncate
9. Split
10. StripHtml
11. Strip
12. Lstrip
13. RsTrip
14. Currency
15. StripNewlines
16. Join
17. Sort
18. Map
19. Replace
20. ReplaceFirst
21. Remove
22. RemoveFirst
23. Append
24. Prepend
25. NewlineToBr
26. Date
27. First
28. Last
29. Plus
30. Minus
31. Times
32. Round
33. DivideBy
34. Modulo
35. Default
36. Uniq
37. Abs
38. AtLeast
39. AtMost
40. Compact

Here you can check its [implementation](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/blob/b6a7d992bf47e7d7dcec36fb402f2e0d70819388/src/DotLiquid/StandardFilters.cs#L326).

JSON template to be transformated as JSON OUTPUT (note: request inputs are inside {{ }}):

```
{%- assign deviceList = content.devices | Split: ', ' -%}

{
   "fullName": "{{content.firstName | Append: ' ' | Append: content.lastName}}",
   "firstNameUpperCase": "{{content.firstName | Upcase}}",
   "phoneAreaCode": "{{content.phone | Slice: 1, 3}}",
   "devices" : [
      {%- for device in deviceList -%}
         {%- if forloop.Last == true -%}
         "{{device}}"
         {%- else -%}
         "{{device}}",
         {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
   ]
}
```

Create a postman to test a POST request with a JSON body matching the content object in your template:

```
{
    "content": {
        "devices": "1,2,3,4,5",
        "firstName": "Dean",
        "lastName": "Ledet",
        "phone": "11111111"
    },
    "integrationAccount": {
        "map": {
            "name": "SimpleJsonToJsonTemplate"
        }
    }
}
```

Replace input Json map for your Liquid map name.

Comment: I understand how to use liquid and its filters to create templates and thanks for the explanation, but I was asking if there's a way to use my own filters in the logic app schema because the DotLiquid implementation of Liquid supports the creation of your own filters.

Comment: Don't think so. Just standard filters found in DotLiquid code.

Comment: @Gutlessmoon7579 Did you find the answer to whether you can use (and how) custom filters in the liquid template on Azure?